# Why don't these animations work when I'm using a storyboard?

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I've created a simple subclass of `StackPanel` that I can move around on the screen using an animated `TranslateTransform`.  It looks like this:

```
public class MovingStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    public void BeginMove(Point translatePosition)
    {
        RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        Duration d = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400));
        DoubleAnimation x = new DoubleAnimation(translatePosition.X, d);
        DoubleAnimation y = new DoubleAnimation(translatePosition.Y, d);
        /*
        Storyboard.SetTarget(x, RenderTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(x, new PropertyPath("X"));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(y, RenderTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(y, new PropertyPath("Y"));

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(x);
        sb.Children.Add(y);
        sb.Completed += sb_Completed;
        sb.Begin();
        */
        RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, x);
        RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, y);
    }

    void sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Completed.");
    }
}
```

And here is my problem:  If I animate the X and Y properties directly, as the code above does, it works.  But if I use the commented-out code above it, which is really the simplest creation of a `Storyboard` in code imaginable, nothing happens.  The animation runs - at least, the Completed event gets raised - but nothing changes on the screen.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what it is.  Every example of creating storyboards in code I've seen looks just like this.  There's obviously something about animations and storyboards that I don't know yet:  what is it?

Comment: FYI - I posted this as a bug on Microsoft Connect.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/723701/storyboard-settarget-only-works-on-uielements-but-throws-no-exception

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537640/separate-animations-work-storyboard-doesnt-why). Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795491/wpf-storyboard-animation-not-working) is helpul.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it turns out, you can't use property path syntax in this case, because the properties being animated aren't properties of a `FrameworkElement`.  At least, that's how I interpret the remarkably bewildering exception that I get when I make the change that Anvaka suggested:

```
Cannot automatically create animation clone for frozen property values on     
'System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform' objects. Only FrameworkElement and 
FrameworkContentElement (or derived) types are supported.
```

To animate those, it seems, I have to use a `NameScope` and use `SetTargetName` to name the `TransformElement`.  Then, as long as I pass the `FrameworkElement` that I set the name scope on to the `Begin` method, the storyboard can find the object and the properties and animate them and it all works.  The end result looks like this:

```
public void BeginMove(Point translatePosition)
{
    NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

    RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
    RegisterName("TranslateTransform", RenderTransform);

    Duration d = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400));
    DoubleAnimation x = new DoubleAnimation(translatePosition.X, d);
    DoubleAnimation y = new DoubleAnimation(translatePosition.Y, d);

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(x, "TranslateTransform");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(x, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(y, "TranslateTransform");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(y, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Children.Add(x);
    sb.Children.Add(y);
    sb.Completed += sb_Completed;

    // you must pass this to the Begin method, otherwise the timeline won't be
    // able to find the named objects it's animating because it doesn't know
    // what name scope to look in

    sb.Begin(this);

}
```

Answer (score 8):

It's [property path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) syntax. The following approach works:

```
public void BeginMove(Point translatePosition)
{
  RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
  Duration d = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400));
  DoubleAnimation x = new DoubleAnimation(translatePosition.X, d);
  DoubleAnimation y = new DoubleAnimation(translatePosition.Y, d);

  Storyboard.SetTarget(x, this);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(x, 
              new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));

  Storyboard.SetTarget(y, this);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(y, 
              new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"));

  Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
  sb.Children.Add(x);
  sb.Children.Add(y);
  sb.Completed += sb_Completed;
  sb.Begin();

  //RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, x);
  //RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, y);
}
```