# Storyboard targeting multiple objects, using SetTarget method, doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, 3d

Can anyone help me trying to find out why this doesn't work.

The brushes variable contains a pre-filled list of brushes.
If I try to apply the `BeginAnimation` directly during the iteration, it works fine. But has a great overhead starting each animation separately...

So I was trying to put all the animations in a single storyboard, and fire them all at once...

```
var storyBoard = new Storyboard();           
var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time));
foreach (Brush brush in brushes) 
{
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation(toValue, duration);

    storyBoard.Children.Add(animation);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(Brush.OpacityProperty));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, brush);
}

storyBoard.Begin();
```

This code simply does nothing (that I can see...).

**Edit:** Still not sure of what is problem with the SetTarget method, either a bug or I'm just not using as it should be. Anyway I solved the problem generating unique names for my brushes at runtime and using the SetTargetName method.

Comment: Shouldn't you be pathing to the property that contains the brush and then the brush opacity?  Something like `new PropertyPath("(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)")` and then you'd see something closer to `StoryBoard.SetTarget(animation, this)` on the next line?  I'm a beginner at best but this seems to be part of the problem.  You want to change the brush of a property on an object, not the brush itself as the target (which I think you can't do anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Storyboard.SettargetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.settargetname.aspx) method instead of `Storyboard.SetTarget`. I prepared working sample for you:

```
var brushes = new string[] { "br1", "br2", "br3" };
var sb = new Storyboard();
var dur = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500.0));
double toValue = 1.0;

foreach (var brush in brushes)
{
  var anim = new DoubleAnimation(toValue, dur);
  Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, brush);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath("(0)", new DependencyProperty[] { Brush.OpacityProperty }));
  sb.Children.Add(anim);
}         

sb.Begin(this);
```

Remember, that in this case you also should set a [Namescope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.aspx) as parameter for `Storyboard.Begin` method.

See also: [Another answers on the Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338714/why-dont-these-animations-work-when-im-using-a-storyboard).

Comment: The code you provided in fact works. But, in the your case you have a string array with names of the brushes. In my solution, the 3D models are loaded from external resource libraries, in witch I cannot assume to be a name for each brush.
Anyway I'm using your solution now, and generating unique names for the brushes at runtime. Meanwhile I'll probably try to find a good way of generating names for all a the Visual3D components.