# WPF Storyboard Animation Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, 3d, storyboard

I have my custom 3D model class (Model) which contains Visual3D element and a `Storyboard` (sb) to hold animations related to that model. I'm trying to rotate the Visual3D element using the `Storyboard` but unfortunately it's not working.

Here is the code snippet

```
public void AnimationRotate(Model model, double duration, double startTime, RepeatBehavior behaviour)
    {

        //Rotate transform 3D
        RotateTransform3D rotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D();

        //assign transform to the model
        model.Visual3D.Transform = Transform3DHelper.CombineTransform(model.Visual3D.Transform, rotateTransform);

        //define the rotation axis
        AxisAngleRotation3D rotateAxis = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 180);

        //create 3D rotation animation
        Rotation3DAnimation rotateAnimation = new Rotation3DAnimation(rotateAxis, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));

        //rotation behaviour
        rotateAnimation.RepeatBehavior = behaviour;

        //start animation from time
        rotateAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(startTime);

        //begin animation - THIS WORKS FINE
       // rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform3D.RotationProperty, rotateAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath(RotateTransform3D.RotationProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, rotateTransform);

        //add animation to the storyboard of the model
        model.sb.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);

        //BUT THIS APPROACH IS NOT WOKRING
        model.sb.Begin();

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340356/1136211).

Instead of using `Storyboard.SetTarget` you need to register a name for the transform and call `Storyboard.SetTargetName`. Furthermore you must call [Storyboard.Begin(FrameworkElement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605709.aspx) and pass a FrameworkElement with the appropriate name scope as parameter (`this` here).

```
RegisterName("RotateTransform", rotateTransform);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(rotateAnimation, "RotateTransform");
...
model.sb.Begin(this);
```

---

Also I guess you need to clear the Storyboard's Children somewhere, or create a new Storyboard whenever the animation is started.