# WPF Propertypath in Transformgroup children located in another Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Here we go again.

I'm working on this wiggleanimation to a usercontrol, which basically sets the RotateTransform.Angle from 20 to 30, Autoreverse = true, repeatbehavior = Forever, nothing special..

However my transformgroup is located in a usercontrol called Bomb, and my animation is created in my mainwindow.

To begin with i tried something like this which didn't work, however a tutorial said it should work, and it looks alot nicer than the next part..

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(wiggleAnimation, ((TransformGroup)bomb.RenderTransform).Children[0])))
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(wiggleAnimation, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
```

Then i tried this, and this has the effect I was looking for, however the code does not look very nice.

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(wiggleAnimation, bomb); 
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(wiggleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
```

So can anyone tell me why the top part isn't working. I'm not given an error on the first part of code, it simply just have no effect when I run my program, and i really wanna optimize as much as I can here.

Kind Regards Max

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14796496/1136211) may be helpful.

Comment: Havn't tried it yet, had to much on my mind, but i'll keep it in mind.. Looks like it could work for my problem :)