# Apply animation to ModelVisual3D in storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a ModelVisual3D. I would like to animate its position in a Viewport3D. I have gotten the code to work with a BoxVisual3D (from HelixToolkit), but the code doesn't work for my ModelVisual3D. The ModelVisual3D should translate along the X axis, but instead it just sits still.

I have essentially copied the working code for my BoxVisual3D to my ModelVisual3D. For now, I am just doing the OffsetX property, but later on I will need to have multiple properties on multiple ModelVisual3Ds animated at once, hence the storyboard.

this is the code that doesn't work:

```
Transform3DGroup modelTransformGroup = (Transform3DGroup)_myModel.Transform;
TranslateTransform3D curTransform = (TranslateTransform3D)modelTransformGroup.Children[1];
var moveX = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1000, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
Storyboard.SetTarget(moveX, curTransform);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveX, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetXProperty));
var sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(moveX);
sb.Begin();
```

Here is some code that works, but won't be sufficient since I need to synchronize many animations at once with the storyboard:

```
Transform3DGroup modelTransformGroup = (Transform3DGroup)_myModel.Transform;
TranslateTransform3D curTransform = (TranslateTransform3D)modelTransformGroup.Children[1];
var moveX = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1000, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
curTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetXProperty, moveX);
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I wanted to add that _myModel.Transform is set as a Transform3DGroup earlier in the code and that the first child is a RotationTransform3D and the second child is a TranslateTransform3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795491/wpf-storyboard-animation-not-working) which also pointed to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338714/why-dont-these-animations-work-when-im-using-a-storyboard/2340356#2340356). Turns out you have to register a name for your transformation and set the target name instead of the target. This is because transformations are not part of FrameworkElement.

Below is my working set of code.

```
Transform3DGroup modelTransformGroup = (Transform3DGroup)_myModel.Transform;
TranslateTransform3D curTransform = (TranslateTransform3D)modelTransformGroup.Children[1];
var moveX = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1000, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
RegisterName("Translate", translate);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(moveX, "Translate");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveX, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetXProperty));
var sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(moveX);
sb.Begin(this);
```

I have tested a couple different model types. It seems this will work for any type of object that inherits Visual3D.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to ask a question here. I really want to know why the codes occur some errors, like: Unable to type into "System. Windows. Media. Media3D. MatrixTransform3D" objects cast to type "System. Windows. Media. Media3D. Transform3DGroup.

```
Transform3DGroup modelTransformGroup = (Transform3DGroup)_myModel.Transform;
TranslateTransform3D curTransform (TranslateTransform3D)modelTransformGroup.Children[1];
```

Comment: Current answer doesn't help with an OP's problem. It's worth to create a separate question for you issue.